# Как запретить игроку отклоняться от оси x и y? Чтобы он ходил ровно по оси x и y

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как запретить игроку отклонять от оси `x` и `y`? Чтобы он ходил ровно по оси `x` и `y`.

```
public class MovingPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
public float speed;
private Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;
private Vector3 change;
void Start (){
    myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}
void Update (){
    change = Vector3.zero;
    change.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    change.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    if(change != Vector3.zero)
    {
        MoveCharacter();
    }
}
void MoveCharacter()
{
    myRigidbody.MovePosition(
    transform.position + change * speed * Time.deltaTime
);
}
}
```

Comment: Изменять только х или только y.

Comment: неужто мой ответ не решил проблему?

Answer (score 0):

1. У `Rigidbody` есть настройка блокирования передвижения или наклона по определенных осях. В окне инспектор у компонента `Rigidbody` вкладка "Constraints" - Freeze Position, Freeze Rotation
   [image: настройки Rigitbody]
2. после этого банально достаточно изменять только нужные вектора в нужных направлениях и не изменять в ненужных.